# Sharepoint issue ListData.svc $expand maximum allowed is 7

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I try this query:

```
http://contoso/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Product()?$expand=OrderDetail/Category,Repository/Country,Repository,Origin,OrderDetail/Order&$select=Id,OrderDetail/Category/Title,Repository/Country/Title,Repository/Title,Origin/Title,OrderDetail/Category/Specification,OrderDetail/Order/ImportDate
```

then i got message: `The request includes 8 $expand segment(s), but the maximum allowed is 7`

Is this impossible, or is there another way of accomplishing this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks Like this hard limit set

Looking around the web I found that for `MS Dynamics CRM 2011` this value is configurable (see MaxExpandCount [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334675.aspx)), at the same time it turned out the same value is **hard-coded** for SharePoint in the **InitializeService method** of `ListDataService (Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq namespace in Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.DataService assembly at GAC)`:

```
public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config) 
{ 
    if (config == null) 
    { 
        throw new ArgumentNullException("config"); 
    } 
    config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All); 
    config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead); 
    config.SetEntitySetPageSize("*", 0x3e8); 
    config.MaxBatchCount = 0x3e8; 
    config.MaxChangesetCount = 100; 
    config.MaxExpandCount = 7; 
    config.MaxExpandDepth = 7; 
    config.MaxObjectCountOnInsert = 100; 
    config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2; 
}
```

He also mentioned one workaround, please check it:
[Maximum Number Of $Expand Segments Using Listdata.Svc](https://pholpar.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/maximum-number-of-expand-segments-using-listdata-svc/)

Comment: I saw that answers but how to edit  config.MaxExpandCount
    config.MaxExpandDepth ?

Comment: i am not developer but one thing I know that playing with hard coded limits is not good as well as easy.

Answer (score 0):

The error

> The request includes 8 $expand segment(s), but the maximum allowed is
>   7.

is encountered since the *maximum* number of related entities that can be included in a single request by using the `$expand` operator for [LINQ to SharePoint provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.linq.aspx) is set to `7`

**About DataServiceConfiguration**

- [DataServiceConfiguration Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceconfiguration(v=vs.113).aspx) is used to manage the
  configuration data for a data service, in our case SharePoint REST service.
- [DataServiceConfiguration.MaxExpandCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.dataserviceconfiguration.maxexpandcount(v=vs.113).aspx) property - gets or sets the maximum number of related entities that can be included in a single request by using the $expand operator

---

One option to bypass this type of limitation would be to *extend* SharePoint REST service and increase `DataServiceConfiguration.MaxExpandCount`

### Implementation

ContosoListData.svc:

```
<%@ServiceHost language="C#" Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressDataServiceHostFactory, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" Service="Contoso.SharePoint.Linq.ContosoListDataService, Contoso.SharePoint.Linq.DataService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=47134954c7026996" %>
```

ContosoListDataService.cs:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq;
using System;
using System.Data.Services;
using System.Data.Services.Common;

namespace Contoso.SharePoint.Linq
{
    public class ContosoListDataService : ListDataService
    {
        public new static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            if (config == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("config");
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);
            config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.AllRead);
            config.SetEntitySetPageSize("*", 1000);
            config.MaxBatchCount = 1000;
            config.MaxChangesetCount = 100;
            config.MaxExpandCount = 14;  //<-- set custom 
            config.MaxExpandDepth = 7;
            config.MaxObjectCountOnInsert = 100;
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        }
    }
}
```

### How to build a solution

- create an `Empty SharePoint Project` in VS (farm solution)
- map `ISAPI` SharePoint Folder and add `ContosoListData.svc`
- add reference to the following assemblies: `Microsoft.SharePoint.dll`,`Microsoft.SharePoint.Linq.dll`, `System.Data.Services.dll`, `System.Data.Services.Client.dll` and `System.ServiceModel.dll`
- add `ContosoListDataService.cs`
- build and deploy package

Once the package is deployed you could verify the query:

```
http://contoso/_vti_bin/contosolistdata.svc/Product()?$expand=OrderDetail/Category,Repository/Country,Repository,Origin,OrderDetail/Order&$select=Id,OrderDetail/Category/Title,Repository/Country/Title,Repository/Title,Origin/Title,OrderDetail/Category/Specification,OrderDetail/Order/ImportDate
```

Comment: first thank you for your detailed answer, i will compile this  to DLL then put it in same folder ? and if i do this  it can affect Sharepoint system ?

Comment: If you are interested, I could share VS project for this solution, it basically consists of assembly (copied into GAC while deployment) and custom REST service (copied into ISAPI folder). Once the package is deployed you could access ContosoListData.svc instead of ListData.svc

Comment: sure it's great suggest -  thank you for taking the time